# QML: Destroy Popup causing access violation in event loop

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

Just when I debug my program which try to destroy a popup which is dynamically created by `Qt.createComponent(...)`, it occasionally occurs exception.

[image]

Here is related code:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    property var dialog
    ...
    Component.onCompleted: {
        var dialogComponent = Qt.createComponent("qrc:/TestPopup.qml")
        dialog = dialogComponent.createObject(...)
        dialog.closed.connect(function(){ [] })
        dialog.open()
    }

    Timer {
    id: timer
    interval: 3000
    triggeredOnStart: false
    running: false
    onTriggered: dialog.destroy()
}
```

TestPopup.qml:

```
Popup {
    id: popup
    modal: true
    ...
    Button {
        text: "close"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        onClicked: popup.close()
    }
}
```

When `[1]` is `dialog.destroy()`, it highly probable occurs an exception.
And when `[1]` is `timer.start()`, it occurs an exception once in a while.

How can I destroy popup safely?

Comment: I don't see any errors in your code, but what you can try is to let the dialog destroy itself.  replace `onClicked: popup.close()` with `onClicked: popup.destroy()` and see if that works without any errors in your program. I'm not sure why you get an exception, my only guess is it has something to do with your Timer or how you create the object (parent object etc).

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: @Mitch I has upload my stack trace image.

Comment: @xander Replacement result in same exception. Can you get anything from stack trace?

Comment: @A.J hard to say it seems like a crash in the `QObject::connect` method, you should run your app in debug mode, seems like that crash happens in normal run mode so its hard to track its origin. But maybe it comes from somewhere else in your code, not what you've shown you know. if you create a minimal example and only test your popup creation adn destruction I'm pretty sure it does not crash.

Comment: The problem has been fixed in Qt 5.9.0 beta and later. Disabling QML debugging in the project's run settings should help as a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace looks similar to [QTBUG-59532](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59532). You could try applying the fixes for that issue, namely https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/189581/ (and maybe https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/189553/ as well, if you're using `SwipeDelegate`). I don't see `SwipeDelegate` in that trace, but it can't hurt to try.

The other thing you could try is running your application with valgrind on Linux, as described [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59532?focusedCommentId=351271&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-351271).